# How can I find the name of the event listener that Twitter uses to load more tweets both when you scroll to the bottom and when you load new tweets?

Tags: javascript, twitter, event-listener

I'm playing around with a Chrome extension for Twitter for a fun project, and I'd like to go through all the tweets that are shown on the page--even if more of them load.

So if the user presses the new-tweets-bar, I want my function to handle those new tweets; and if the user scrolls all the way to the bottom (thus loading older tweets), I want my function to handle those.
I thought the most straightforward way would be for those events to re-call my function, either only for the new tweets (optimal) or for the whole page again.

But how do I figure out what the names of those events are? I've looked at Firebug and its profile command; and at Allan Jardine's Visual Event 2, but neither of them were really that helpful to me in this case.

1) Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Is there a better way to go through all new tweets on a page?

2) Is there some way to get the name of the triggering event(s)?

3) Do you have any advice on using Firebug or Visual Event?